Microsoft SSIS - Issues switching from attunity driver to new Microsoft Oracle Connector v1.3
First some facts :
I'm facing some issues when trying to use the Microsoft Oracle Connector v1.3 in SSIS packages. The servers at the company I'm working for are being migrated to SQL 2022, so the previously used attunity driver is now obsolete.
The Oracle driver from Microsoft was deployed on our workstations and now everytime I want to open the Oracle source on the data flow part of the package I get this message (The connection manager was set with Attunity driver):

If I try to create another Oracle connection manager, using this Conn Manager type :

Once I click on test connection the wizard window just close, without any error
I have no admin rights on my WS so I tried several combination of tools / versions and could not achieve to find the good one.
I even tried to downgrade Data Tools as I could see that Oracle driver is not supported in newer ones, but with no success.
At the moment my components versions are :
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.33
SQL Server Data Tools 16.0.62205.05200
SQL Server Integration Services 15.0.1900.73
Hoping that somebody here may have had the same issue, and so, some advice
Thanks in advance

Solved by :

Making a clean install of VS 2019
Making a clean install of SSIS for VS 4.6
Installing Microsoft Oracle Connector for SSIS 1.3 for SQL2022

